# Ember service property with promise data

Tags: ember.js

I have a service to get the current user and it returns correctly when I return a hardcoded object, but I can't get it to return data from an ajax call.

```
export default  Ember.Service.extend({
  currentUser: Ember.computed(function() {
    Ember.$.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/v1/me/"
    }).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    },
    function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
  }),
});
```

I know the data is being returned correctly, according to the `console.log` in the promise.

When I use this service in a controller, it is returning nothing for the currentUser, however I know everything is hooked up correctly because if i substitute an Ember.Object in for the ajax query, it returns that object to the Controller.

Do I need to do something special with the property that contains the ajax query to be able to use the returned data in a controller?

Comment: `Ember.$.ajax` returns an "ajax promise" not a Promises/A+ promise, so you will have problems there. You are also not actually returning the `Ember.$.ajax` call, so the return value of the method is undefined. Additionally you might have to wrap the call in an ObjectProxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it will work in the way you want it to. At least I never read that you can return a promise as computed property. What you can do is get current user from server when client authorizes and save it for example in local storage. And in your computed property read data from local storage and return it.

[Here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practice-for-loading-and-persisting-current-user-in-an-authenticated-system/6987/12) you may find an interesting discussion, that helped me in the same situation. If you use ember-simple-auth, you'll even find there a ready to use piece of code.

Comment: But when ember-simple-auth release 1.0, the creator of  `ember-simple-auth` make a post at `http://log.simplabs.com/post/131698328145/updating-to-ember-simple-auth-10`, He abide by promise instead of local storage for get currentUser